# column graph with datetime xaxis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a beginner in d3.js and was trying to plot a column graph with datetime x axis. Can anyone help me clear the mistake in this code. Thanks in advance for any reply.

```
var data = [{
                "time": "01:00:00",
                "total": 1
            }, {
                "time": "01:05:30",
                "total": 2
            }, {
                "time": "02:10:00",
                "total": 1
            }, {
                "time": "03:15:30",
                "total": 3
            }, {
                "time": "04:25:30",
                "total": 1
            }, {
                "time": "07:55:15",
                "total": 4
            }, {
                "time": "12:18:00",
                "total": 1
            }, {
                "time": "17:00:00",
                "total": 5
            }];

            var margin = {
                top: 40,
                right: 40,
                bottom: 40,
                left: 40
            },
            width = 800,
            height = 500;

            var today = new Date();
            today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            var todayMillis = today.getTime();

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                var parts = d.time.split(/:/);
                var timePeriodMillis = (parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 * 60 * 1000) +
                                       (parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 60 * 1000) + 
                                       (parseInt(parts[2], 10) * 1000);

                d.time = new Date();
                d.time.setTime(todayMillis + timePeriodMillis);
            });

            var x = d3.time.scale()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }))
                .nice(d3.time.day, 1)
                .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom]).domain([0,
                     d3.max(data, function (d) {
                     return d.y;
                      })
                    ]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient('bottom')
                .ticks(d3.time.hour, 2)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'))
                .tickSize(5)
                .tickPadding(8);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient('left')
                .tickPadding(8)
                .tickSize(5)
                .tickSubdivide(true);

            var svg = d3.select('#plot_container').append('svg')
                .attr('class', 'chart')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

            svg.selectAll('.chart')
                .data(data)
                .enter().append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'bar')
                .attr('x', function (d) {
                    return x(d.time);
                })
                .attr('y', function (d) {
                  return y(d.total);
                })
                .attr('width', 0)
                .attr('height', function (d) {
                  return ((height - margin.bottom) - y(d.y));
                })

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ')')
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'y axis')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margin.left) + ',0)')
                .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Try to make your code simpler and shorter with less data and options, and describe the expected result and your result so far.

Comment: So far i got x axis with time (2 hr interval) and y axis without any detail in it.Also the graph is not plotted within.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems:

- bar width defined as zero;
- y scale with an unknown value(d.y);
- bar height using the same unknown value(d.y);
- y scale with `margin.bottom` and `margin.top` in the wrong position;
- Wrong `translate` for y axis.

Solving these problems, here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/3rsv3d83/2/

You still have several issues to solve, but this is a start.

Comment: Thanku for helping me out and sharing the info.